# Use another token as validator in solidity

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets

I want to develop a contract where to call a function you need to have a certain amount of another token in your wallet.Lets say if a user have 10 of this token

> (0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4)

in his wallet then only he can call the setName function.

code

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT


contract Validator{

    string name;
    address token= 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4;


    function setName(string memory _name)public {
        require();
        name=_name;
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, You first need to initialize the token interface on the contract instead of its address. Then create a modifier to querry the calling address' balance. sample below.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
```

//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

import {IERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
contract Validator{

```
string name;
IERC20 token= IERC20(0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4);

modifier hasBalance() {
    require(token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= 
    balanceAllowedTocallTransaction, "not enough");
_;

constructro(){}


function setName(string memory _name)public hasBalance {
    name=_name;
}
```

}

Comment: is there any other way , without implement the erc20 interface?

Comment: `pragma solidity ^0.8.0;



contract Validator{

    string name;
    address token= 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4;
    mapping (address =>uint)   validator;

    function setName(string memory _name)public {
        require(validator[token]>10,"not enough token");
        name=_name;
    }
    

}`